# Interactive Viewer zoom image does not work

Tags: flutter

The zoom in my image does not work, I try to pass my fingers but the image does not increase and decrease, if someone can help me I would appreciate it:

```dart
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ImageScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final url;

  ImageScreen({
    Key key,
    @required this.url,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: InteractiveViewer(
        boundaryMargin: const EdgeInsets.all(22.0),
        minScale: 0.6,
        maxScale: 2.6,
        child: Container(
          child: CachedNetworkImage(
            imageUrl: '${this.url}',
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this plugin [here](https://pub.dev/packages/zoomable_image).
you can pass the image to the next page when you click then use the plugin to zoom

Comment: but how would it look in my code?